# Declaring a vector of trait objects with a lifetime parameter

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a `Widget` trait parametrised on a context type:

```
trait Widget<C> {
    fn f<'a>(&self, ctx: &'a mut C);
}
```

Some widgets whose context types are the same, but contain references so are parameterised:

```
struct Ctxt<'c> {
    data: &'c u32,
}

struct W1 {}
struct W2 {}

impl<'c> Widget<Ctxt<'c>> for W1 { // and W2
    fn f<'a>(&self, ctx: &'a mut Ctxt<'c>) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

I have a multi-widget which wants to store several of these:

```
struct WV {
    widgets: Vec<Box<Widget<Ctxt<????>>>>,
}

impl<'c> Widget<Ctxt<'c>> for WV {
    fn f<'a>(&self, ctx: &'a mut Ctxt<'c>) {
        for w in &self.widgets {
            w.f(ctx);
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like I need a `Vec<Box<Widget<for<'c> Ctxt<'c>>>>`; but you can't do that!  Alternatively, only specifying the lifetime in the definition of `f`:

```
impl Widget<Ctxt> for W {
    fn f<'a, 'c>(&self, ctx: &'a mut Ctxt<'c>) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either (missing lifetime parameter for `Ctxt`).

The purpose of the context is to pass a mutable reference to something long-lived which is only needed during `f`; the `&mut` reference can't be stored in `W1` etc. I don't really want to specify any lifetimes for `Ctxt`.

How can I store multiple implementers of the trait, which allow passing in a context containing references?

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but why not use `struct WV<'c> { widgets: Vec<Box<Widget<Ctxt<'c>>>> }`? All of the lifetimes have to be known statically and this would unify them all.

Comment: The lifetime isn't known until actually calling `f` when you have a context to pass in. Currently (without `WV`) I just store a `W1` which has no lifetime parameters, and when callling `w1.f()` the trait is effectively specialized for `Ctxt<'c>` at that moment. Next time `w1.f()` is called it may be on `Widget<Ctxt<'d>>`; but the `w1` is the same. The creation doesn't happen in the same scope as the method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a night's sleep, I think I have an answer.  I can defer the selection of the `Ctxt` lifetime by indirecting through a new trait `CtxtWidget`, and `impl<'c> Widget<Ctxt<'c>>` for the new trait:

```
trait Widget<C> {
    fn f<'a>(&self, ctx: &'a mut C);
}

struct W1 {}
struct W2 {}
struct Ctxt<'c> {
    data: &'c u32,
}

trait CtxtWidget {
    fn ctxt_f<'a, 'c>(&self, ctx: &'a mut Ctxt<'c>);
}

impl CtxtWidget for W1 {
    fn ctxt_f<'a, 'c>(&self, ctx: &'a mut Ctxt<'c>) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
impl CtxtWidget for W2 {
    fn ctxt_f<'a, 'c>(&self, ctx: &'a mut Ctxt<'c>) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl<'c> Widget<Ctxt<'c>> for Box<CtxtWidget> {
    fn f<'a>(&self, ctx: &'a mut Ctxt<'c>) {
        self.ctxt_f(ctx);
    }
}

struct WV {
    pub widgets: Vec<Box<CtxtWidget>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut wv = WV{widgets: Vec::new()};
    wv.widgets.push(Box::new(W1{}));
    wv.widgets.push(Box::new(W2{}));
    let u = 65u32;
    let mut ctxt = Ctxt{data: &u};
    for widget in &wv.widgets {
        widget.f(&mut ctxt);
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=62bef54b7f56b8b86bc0b152b5ab262a&version=stable&backtrace=0))

In effect `CtxtWidget` is roughly equivalent to `for<'c> Widget<Ctxt<'c>>`.

I'd still be interested in any other solutions (including intrusive changes if there's a better way to do this).